# Drawing control to memory (Bitmap)

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, controls, render

Is it possible to draw a wpf control to memory (Bitmap) without drawing on the screen at all?
I found an example of how to save to Bitmap, but it only works when the window has been drawn in the screen.

```
BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)canvaspad.Width,
    (int)canvaspad.Height,
    96,
    96,
    System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
renderTarget.Render(canvaspad);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the control has no parent container, you need to call [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) and [Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx) in order to do a proper layout. As layout is done asynchronously (see Remarks in [Measure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.measure.aspx) and [Arrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.arrange.aspx)), you may also need to call [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx) to force the layout to be updated immediately.

```
public BitmapSource RenderToBitmap(UIElement element, Size size)
{
    element.Measure(size);
    element.Arrange(new Rect(size));
    element.UpdateLayout();

    var bitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

    bitmap.Render(element);
    return bitmap;
}
```

---

In case you have already set the `Width` and `Height` of the element you may use that for the size parameter:

```
var grid = new Grid
{
    Width = 200,
    Height = 200,
    Background = Brushes.Yellow
};

grid.Children.Add(
    new Ellipse
    {
        Width = 100,
        Height = 100,
        Fill = Brushes.Blue
    });

var bitmap = RenderElement(grid, new Size(grid.Width, grid.Height));
```

Comment: This scheme does not work!
At least on my Grid Control contains a few items inside.
As long as the item is not rendered on the screen in bitmap black rectangle.