# Is it possible to make a screenshots of a UIElement built in code-behind and not shown?

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot, screen-capture, uielement

I would like to know if it is possible to "screenshot" an element without showing it on screen.

For example, this `StackPanel`:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
    sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Bouton 1" });
    sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Bouton 2" });
    sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Bouton 3" });
    sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Bouton 4" });
    sp.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Bouton 5" });

    // Take screenshot of sp
}
```

I don't think this is possible, as there is no rendered size, but I'd like to be sure.

Thanks !

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124825/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-wpf-window

Comment: It won't work, as it requires a size.  I don't know the size as the element has not been shown.

Comment: It will work, but you will have to call `Measure` and `Arrange` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14953281/1136211).

Comment: Thanks Clemens !  It does work.  Do you want to answer the question, so I'd accept your answer ?