# Render a hidden canvas without showing it?

Tags: .net, wpf

I want to store a canvas on disk as a PNG image.

This works when the canvas is completely shown using this code:

```
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(794, 1122, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(canvas);
```

But parts that are not shown at that time are not rendered.
When the visual is not shown at all, nothing is rendered.

Then how can I save Canvas build in code to disc without showing it?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14119523/401828

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's the same code I currently use. UpdateLayout() didn't fix it either

Comment: Only solution I can come up with is to put my Canvas in a FlowDocument and save this.

Comment: The canvas has to get a layout, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14953281/1136211).

Comment: Measure() and Arrange() did the trick. But my PNG still is mainly black. Is seems that it's not using my white background brush of the canvas..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've got it fixed with the help of heltonbiker & Clemens.

```
var size = new Size(794, 122);
Document.Measure(size);
Document.Arrange(new Rect(size));

Document.UpdateLayout();

RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(794, 1122, 96d, 96d, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(Document);
```

But when I save my canvas to disc it had a black background. I solved this by adding a `Rectangle` to my XAML inside the Canvas.

Comment: The answer code does is not complete and it's hard to get the idea.